# SendGrid Marketing Campaigns - Adding Super/Sub script without code

Tags: sendgrid

We are using the Marketing Campaigns side of SendGrid, and in the design editor are trying to see if there is a way to superscript or subscript text without having to change the entire text block to code.

We created a text block, added our text which needs a superscript on a link, and when we go into the code to edit it (add <sup>1</sup>), as we can't find a WYSIWIG solution, it changes the entire text block into an HTML code block.

Trying to find out if anyone knows if this is *always* going to be the case, or if we are just missing the WYSIWIG option to add this in. I can only see bold, italic, underline, bullets, numbering, indent, text justification.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The WYSIWIG section of the template editor for a text block looks like this:

[image: Bold, Italic, Underline, Link, Numbered Bullets, Bullet Points, Decrease Indent, Increase Indent, Reset Styles]

You are not, to my knowledge, missing a superscript option.

When you make a change to the code that is not supported in the WYSIWIG editor, the module must be changed to a code module. As the interface says:

> You have made structural HTML changes that this module doesn't support. Typically this happens when you add a tag such as '`<span>`', '`<p>`', '`<table>`', etc. To keep these changes, convert to a code module.

If you need the superscript, but prefer to use WYSIWIG for most things, you could try to split the text into multiple modules in which the paragraph containing the superscript is a code module, but is surrounded by text modules.